# Node Express RESTful API default engine for error handling

Tags: node.js, rest, express, error-handling

I am working on a set of RESTful API services built using Node.js Express, and when it gets an error a stack-trace follows preceded with:

> Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.

I have read several previous Stack Overflow articles about expected code within app.js for handling errors:

```
// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});
```

However, for default engine, the StackOverflow recommendations focus on using Vue with Jade.

This is an internal RESTful API service and I would prefer not to add a default engine outputting error response in Jade.

Recommendations?

This is an example stack-trace from my RESTful API service:

```
[09:22:42] info: GET /api/v1/archives/google/folders 401 130ms
Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
    at new View (/Users/jeff/github/jeff00/act-archive/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:61:11)
    at Function.render (/Users/jeff/github/jeff00/act-archive/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:570:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (/Users/jeff/github/jeff00/act-archive/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1008:7)
    at /Users/jeff/github/jeff00/act-archive/app.js:137:7
    at Layer.handle_error (/Users/jeff/github/jeff00/act-archive/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:71:5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `res.render` calls because of which Express expects a rendering engine to be set for the application. Remove the `res.render` and do something like `res.json` and this error won't come up.

Comment: Hi @faizuddin-mohammed. I have tried using `res.json` before, recommend by another StackOverflow article and I get a warning: `express deprecated res.json(status, obj): Use res.status(status).json(obj) instead`, and an error: `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Oh, just use the `res.status(404).json(errObj)` and get rid of all the other `res.*` calls.

Comment: Hi @faizuddin-mohammed. Yes, in my last comment and prior to your comment, I had tried just using `res.status(404).json(errObj)`, however, I get `[ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]`.

Comment: Did you remove the other `res.status` call?